# Determine number of rows in DataGridView except of new row

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How can I accuretely determine number of rows in DataGridView *except of new row* (the row with asterisk)?

**If I start typing into new row and then cancel it by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>**, another new row created in the meantime disappears and original row becomes new row again. But it no longer has its `IsNewRow` property set to `true`. And `DataGridView.NewRowIndex` is suddenly set to `-1`.

**How I can correctly count rows except the new row including the above special case?** ([Temporary reset of `NewRowIndex` to `-1` (also affecting `IsNewRow`) is a "feature" of DataGridView.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,5396))

(C# or VB – whatever you prefer.)

---

For those who were unable to find the special case above –
just handle `DataGridView.UserDeletedRow` and there it is:

```vb
Sub DataGridView1_UserDeletedRow1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.UserDeletedRow

    ' reveal problem with DataGridView1.NewRowIndex
    Debug.Print($"NewRowIndex={DataGridView1.NewRowIndex}")

    ' reveal problem with row.IsNewRow
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Debug.Print($"Row {row.Index}: IsNewRow={row.IsNewRow}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Steps:

1. Create WinForms VB project.
2. Add `DataGridView1`.
3. Add 2 text columns into the `DataGridView1`.
4. Add the above event handler.
5. Launch.
6. Focus first column and type `a`.
7. Immediately quit edit mode by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
8. See the result. The above handler prints `NewRowIndex=-1`, but it should print number `>= 0`. Last `IsNewRow` value is `false`, but it should be `true`.

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if your grid used a DataSource.

Comment: You need to bind the DGV to a data source whom implements the [ICancelAddNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icanceladdnew(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. A good choice would be the [BindingList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @LarsTech – I understand, but why to limit myself to mandatory DataSource? After some analysis, I think I have found [the proper way of calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33027006/2392157).

Comment: With or without using a data source datagridview behave correct. Always you can use `NewRowIndex` of datagridview and `IsNewRow` of row to find out if a row is new row. I couldn't reproduce an abnormal behavior.

Comment: Hope you can share a simple code to reproduce an abnormal behavior of datagridview.

Comment: @RezaAghaei – Question updated with detailed steps. I can consistently reproduce that. Are you able to reproduce it now, too?

Comment: Thank you for updating the question and reproducing the problem, I'll take a look at the problem and will share my idea if I have an idea.

Comment: @RezaAghaei – after further research I have the correct answer and I am sure that per current implementation of DataGridView, nothing better can exist. See updated Q and updated A. That weird "bug" is actually a feature of DataGridView implementation. Thus, no way around it except of own calculations in the same way as DataGridView does internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is by design ([confirmed by the Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1884190/datagridview-newrowindex-cannot-be-detected-1-during-event-datagridview1-userdeletedrow)). Workaround calculations are needed to achieve the result.

There is no other event (than already used `DataGridView.UserDeletedRow`) suitable for calculation covering the special case. And in that event, key values are [temporarily incorrect – see the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,5396).

The only way seems to be take the calculations from the .NET reference source of `DataGridView` and `DataGridViewRow`.

The calculations below assume that

- New row is present if and only if `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` is `true`.
- If new row is present, it is always positioned as the last record.

Let's calculate:

#### Row count except of new row

```
= DataGridView1.Rows.Count - (DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows ? 1 : 0)
```

And unlike original properties which have problems, these calculations seem to **always succeed:**

#### `DataGridView.NewRowIndex`

```
= (DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows ? DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 : -1)
```

---

#### `DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow`

```
= row.DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows && (row.Index == row.DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
```

---

Implemented as [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) extension methods:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Row count including only standard rows, i.e. without new row.
''' </summary>
<Extension>
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Function StandardRowCountᛎ(dataGridView As DataGridView) As Integer
    Return dataGridView.Rows.Count - If(dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows, 1, 0)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' The same as <see cref="DataGridView.NewRowindex"/> but reliable also after cancelled new record.
''' </summary>
<Extension>
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Function NewRowIndexᛎ(dataGridView As DataGridView) As Integer
    Return If(dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows, dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1, -1)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' The same as <see cref="DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow"/> but reliable also after cancelled new record.
''' </summary>
<Extension>
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Function IsNewRowᛎ(row As DataGridViewRow) As Boolean
    Return row.DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows AndAlso row.Index = row.DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
End Function
```

After replacing standard calls by calls to these methods, I noticed that couple of other subtle bugs got fixed in my project, which seemed to be related to presence of new record row.

Answer (score 2):

Check this post on MSDN: [system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) (**carefully read the Remarks section**) and this MSDN Forum post [datagridview-cancel-add-new-row](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a7d80d9-82c3-48c9-a155-00c444e49bb2/datagridview-cancel-add-new-row?forum=Vsexpressvb)

You may use `DataGridView.AllowNew` property as workaround for your solution.

1. Set the `DataGridView.AllowNew = False`
   This should remove the new insert row
2. Count DataGridView rows
   `DataGridView.Rows.Count` or `DataGridView.RowCount` (whichever is your requirement)
3. Again set `DataGridView.AllowNew = True` to show blank row for adding new record (if required)

I have NOT tested the code snippet but this should solve the problem

**Edit:**
Just found two more articles related to your question, may be useful for your reading:

1. [adding-a-new-row-to-the-datagridview-programmatically-datagridviewallowusertoaddrow-false](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07c1732a-d8c7-4f01-bb8a-1a3aec642ce8/adding-a-new-row-to-the-datagridview-programmatically-datagridviewallowusertoaddrow-false-and?forum=winformsdatacontrols)
2. [how-to-cancel-an-add-new-by-pressing-escape](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e516cfe-c9d3-4f4d-b3e5-d91bdbd39f4a/how-to-cancel-an-add-new-by-pressing-escape?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the something like this

```
DataGridView dg = ...;
var rowCount = dg.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) -
    (dg.NewRowIndex >= 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

I've tested it in both bound and unbound mode and it works correctly. Btw, I wasn't able to reproduce the special case you mentioned - `IsNewRow` property was always returning a correct value.

Here is my test code:

```
//#define fBoundMode

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
#if fBoundMode
            dg.DataSource = new BindingList<Data>();
#else
            dg.Columns.Add("Foo", "Foo");
            dg.Columns.Add("Bar", "Bar");
#endif
            var status = new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, AutoSize = false, Parent = form };
            var timer = new Timer { Interval = 250, Enabled = true };
            timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var rowCount = dg.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) - (dg.NewRowIndex >= 0 ? 1 : 0);
                status.Text = "Rows: " + rowCount;
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }
#if fBoundMode
        class Data
        {
            public string Foo { get; set; }
            public string Bar { get; set; }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** As for the special case (which you should have clearly provided from the beginning - event now it's not clear until one hits the code example, and I don't think this site is a place for puzzles) I find it very exceptional and the "correct" solution provided in your own answer

```
rowCount = dg.Rows.Count - (dg.AllowUserToAddRows? 1 : 0);
```

may work for your **specific** needs, but cannot be used as a general advice (which it seems to pretend to be) because apparently doesn't work with invisible rows or bound mode to a data source with AddNew disabled, as you may see in the example below:

```
//#define fBoundMode

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
#if fBoundMode
            dg.DataSource = new BindingList<Data>(new List<Data> { new Data { Foo = "a" }, new Data { Foo = "b" } }) { AllowNew = false };
#else
            dg.Columns.Add("Foo", "Foo");
            dg.Columns.Add("Bar", "Bar");
            dg.Rows.Add("a", "a");
            dg.Rows.Add("b", "b");
            dg.Rows.Add("c", "c");
            dg.Rows[1].Visible = false;
#endif
            var status = new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, AutoSize = false, Parent = form };
            Action updateStatus = () =>
            {
                var rowCount = dg.Rows.Count - (dg.AllowUserToAddRows ? 1 : 0);
                status.Text = "Rows: " + rowCount;
            };
            dg.UserDeletedRow += (sender, e) => updateStatus();
            var timer = new Timer { Interval = 250, Enabled = true };
            timer.Tick += (sender, e) => updateStatus();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
#if fBoundMode
        class Data
        {
            public string Foo { get; set; }
            public string Bar { get; set; }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

I personally think the case you mentioned is not "by design", but rather than a result of some technical (implementation) difficulties. As being such, I would rather treat is as exception (with special code) rather than trying to generalize it. But that's up to you - I'm definitely not going to spend more time on this .

Comment: Thank you for effort. However, in my case `DataGridView.NewRowIndex` and `row.IsNewRow` are giving wrong results. Please see exact reproduction steps in updated answer.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for your Update part, I did not realize those other possible scenarios. In no way I wanted to post puzzles for anybody, it simply did not work correctly when I was relying on DataGridView.

Comment: @miroxlav You are welcome. And no problem, this answer is from my early days in SO, nowadays I wouldn't write it the way I did here :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the number of rows in DataGridView except the new row, there is an additional solution using LINQ.

**C#:**

```
DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r=>!r.IsNewRow).Count()
```

**VB.Net**

```
DataGridView1.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().Where(Function(r) Not r.IsNewRow).Count()
```

Comment: This is good as theoretic solution but in practice I would avoid this, because iterating record-by-record just to get the count (which is already calculated and available somewhere else) is highly ineffective. Extra CPU time and even disk activity (swapping memory) may be involved in case of large data sets. So this can be used as last resort if all other methods were unreliable. But currently they are fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment